# How to change the order of elements in an array using a pointer?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

For example, I have an array:

```
int Arr[10]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
```

How to change its order of elements using a pointer to receive the following array:

```
Arr={10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1}

to change the order odd and even using a pointer I've found this:
But I need only to reverse an array (without replacing odd and even)
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main (const int& Argc, const char* Argv[]){

const int Nelem=10;
int Arr[]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
int *begAr=&Arr[0];
int *endAr=&Arr[Nelem];
int *itrAr=begAr;
int *tmpValAr=new int(0);
cout<<"Before\t1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10"<<endl;
while(itrAr<endAr){
*tmpValAr=*itrAr;
*itrAr=*(itrAr+1);
*(itrAr+1)=*tmpValAr;
itrAr+=2;
}
cout<<"After\t";
for(int i=0; i<Nelem; ++i)cout<<Arr[i]<<" ";
cout<<endl;
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean using a pointer ? you want to use an algorithm for sorting but using only pointers ?

Comment: yes, especially pointers.
Does it matter what array - static or dynamic to sort using a pointer?

Comment: @user2553675 Do you really want code that will run under both C and C++?  Is this really a C question where the C++ tag is added just to get more responses?  Or is it a C++ question, but if the most elegant answer turns out to be C-compatible that would be ok too?

Comment: @user2553675: It matters a lot. It also matters what you are actually trying to accomplish. Do you want to simply reverse an array? Or do you want to be able to actually sort it. Also: C or C++, which language are you using? reversing an array is easily accomplished by creating a new array, and assigning `newArray[idx] = old[length - idx];` in a loop

Comment: Simply reverse an array using a pointer.
Language - c++.
IDE - MS VS 2010.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, a C-style approach using pointers to reverse an array? That shouldn't be too hard to figure out. Here's one approach:

```
int main ( void )
{
    int i,//temp var
        arr[10]= {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};//the array
    int *start = &arr[0],//pointer to the start of the array
        *end = &arr[9];//pointer to the last elem in array
    //print out current arr values
    for (i=0;i<10;++i)
        printf("arr[%d] = %d\n", i, arr[i]);
    do
    {//simple loop
        i = *start;//assign whatever start points to to i
        *start = *end;//assign value of *end to *start
        *end = i;//assign initial value of *start (stored in i) to *end
    } while ( ++start < --end);//make sure start is < end, increment start and decrement end
    //check output:
    for (i=0;i<10;++i)
        printf("arr[%d] = %d\n", i, arr[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see [here](https://ideone.com/CcCy6E), this reverses the array just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Use [reverse](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/reverse/) found in `<algorithm>`:

```
std::reverse(Arr, Arr+10);
```

It will reverse a set of data like you are requesting.

This is the approximate implementation of the function, which you could adapt if necessary to your needs if you would like to write the loop yourself:

```
template <class BidirectionalIterator>
  void reverse (BidirectionalIterator first, BidirectionalIterator last)
{
  while ((first!=last)&&(first!=--last)) {
    std::iter_swap (first,last);
    ++first;
  }
}
```

If you are in C or would like a less general solution, do something like this:

```
int i = 0; j = 9;
for(;i<j;++i;--j) {
  int tmp = arr[i];
  arr[i] = arr[j];
  arr[j] = arr[i];
}
```

Comment: @haccks, This does use two pointers: `Arr` (after decay) and `Arr+10`. Beyond that, it's just copying the implementation of `std::reverse` into your own function, and what's the point, really?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt; Of course a good solution but not answering the question.

Comment: You must know more of the question than what is written here, so you are probably right.

Comment: @chris; How do you do this in C ?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt; Yes, I do. That's why I can see both C and C++ tag in the question.

Comment: @haccks Instead of pestering this responder, why don't you focus on improving your answer so that it will be upvoted and accepted.  In specific, provide an actual self-contained compilable, executable code segment, and an explanation.  If you don't like this answer, downvote it if you wish.  But if you want to provide a positive contribution, you'll make your answer the best it can be.

Comment: @haccks ok if you would like pointers...replace `arr[i]` with `*(arr+i)`....wow pointers!

Comment: @DavidO; I don't know how you called it *pestering*. Another thing is that, I am not gonna post code for this. OP should have do this him/herself until he post a code that what he tried.

Comment: @haccks, If a question has both tags, I say fair grounds for giving a solution in either one. If the OP wants a C solution, but tags it C++ as well and doesn't say they need a C solution, they ignored several opportunities.

Answer (score 1):

Take two pointers `begAr` pointing at `arr[0]` and `endAr` pointing at `arr[9]`. Traverse the array from both sides and swap `*begAr` with `*endAr` until `begAr > endAr`.

```
int tempValAr;
while(endAr >= begAr )
{
    tempValAr = *begAr;
    *begAr++ = *endAr;
    *endAr-- = tempValAr;
}
```

See the [test program](http://ideone.com/GI8BMx).

Comment: I suppose that what is what I need.
Could you provide piece of code?

Comment: Could you provide what code you have written for this?

Comment: what is "temp" in your code?
How I should apply this var to my array?

Comment: @user2553675; I changed the variable names to your variable names. Declare `tempValAr` as `int`, not pointers. Now it will work.